# Crontab not Executes my python file but output is not generated...!

Tags: python, mysql, cron, sensors

cronjob working perfectly but out is not generated, !!! when i run my python script manually it gives output , but in cron job it was not generating output

```
Dec 23 15:10:01 raspberrypi CRON[3265]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/sensor_baloon.py >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 23 15:11:01 raspberrypi CRON[3334]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/sensor_baloon.py >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 23 15:12:01 raspberrypi CRON[3355]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/sensor_baloon.py >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 23 15:13:01 raspberrypi CRON[3482]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/sensor_baloon.py >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 23 15:14:01 raspberrypi CRON[3569]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/sensor_baloon.py >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

this is my working code without any error..!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time,os

import datetime


TRIG = 24
ECHO = 23
ALARM = 17

# Speed of sound in cm/s at temperature
temperature = 20
speedSound = 34326 + (0.6*temperature)

print("Ultrasonic Measurement")
print("Speed of sound is",speedSound/100,"m/s at ",temperature,"deg")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

GPIO.setup(ALARM,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(ALARM, True)

print ("Waiting For Sensor To Settle")
time.sleep(1) #settling time 

def get_distance():
    dist_add = 0
    k=0
    for x in range(30):
        try:
            GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
            time.sleep(0.00001)
            GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

            while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
                pulse_start = time.time()

            while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
                pulse_end = time.time()

            pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
            
            distance = pulse_duration * speedSound

            distance = round(distance, 1)
            distance = distance/2
            print (x, "distance: ", distance)
        
            if(distance > 125):# ignore erroneous readings (max distance cannot be more than 125)
                k=k+1
                continue
        
            dist_add = dist_add + distance
            #print "dist_add: ", dist_add
            time.sleep(.1) # 100ms interval between readings
        
        except Exception as e: 
        
            pass
    
    
    print ("x: ", x+1)
    print ("k: ", k) 
    avg_dist=dist_add/(x+1 -k)
    dist=round(avg_dist,2)
    #print ("dist: ", dist)
    return dist

def sendData_to_remoteServer(url,dist):
    url_full=url+str(dist)
    urlopen(url_full)
    print("sent to url: ",url_full)
    
def low_level_warning(dist):
    level=114-dist
    if(level<40):
        print("level low : ", level)
        GPIO.output(ALARM, False)
    else:
        GPIO.output(ALARM, True)
        print("level ok")
        
from urllib.request import urlopen



#local web server is running 
url_remote="http://localhost/web_host/watertank/insert_data_baloon.php?level="

distance=get_distance()

print ("distance: ", distance ,"cm") 

sendData_to_remoteServer(url_remote,distance)

low_level_warning(distance)

print ("---------------------")
```

Comment: Why don't you output to a log file then you will be able to see what is happening when cron runs your script e.g.: `/home/pi/Desktop/sensor_baloon.py >>/tmp/mylog.log 2>&1` Crontab will not run with your usual environment. Often the PATH will not be the same in cron as it is in your user login. See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: output is generated and than sent to /dev/null

Comment: log file is empty and doesn't generate output.....  @codlord

Comment: Read your input: You are telling cron to discard your output, then you complain that there is no output.

Comment: `/home/pi/Desktop/A.py: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/A.py: import: not found
/home/pi/Desktop/A.py: 2: /home/pi/Desktop/A.py: import: not found
/home/pi/Desktop/A.py: 3: /home/pi/Desktop/A.py: count: not found
/home/pi/Desktop/A.py: 6: /home/pi/Desktop/A.py: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "then")`   iam just getting this kind of log ... but i need to execute my python file

Answer (score 6):

Output of jobs run from crontab are not displayed on the screen. In order to see the output of a cron job, you need to capture it in a file. You can do so by adding

`>> /home/myuser/myscript.log 2>&1`

after the command in your crontab (of course, replace `/home/myuser/myscript.log` by the actual log file you want to use). The `2>&1` will redirect error output to the first file descriptor that receives standard output, so it will be included in the file

Traditionally, such output would be mailed using the local mailer daemon to the owner of the job.